# Evaluate an integral using polar $\int\limits_0^2 \int\limits_{-4\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{4\sqrt{4-x^2}}(x^2-y^2)\,dy\,dx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

How do you evaluate the following integral using polar cordinates.

$$\int_0^2 \int_{-4\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{4\sqrt{4-x^2}}(x^2-y^2)\:\mathrm{d}y\:\mathrm{d}x$$

I converted it to polar coordinate making it a circle with radius of 2.

$$r^2=x^2+y^2$$

I did

$$\int_0^2 (-1)(r^2)(r)\:\mathrm{d}r$$

which equals $-4$. Then the next step

$$\int_\frac{3\pi}{2}^\frac{\pi}{2}-4\: \mathrm{d}\theta$$

Then I get $4\theta$. Plug in my values but I am not sugesting the correct answer $0$.

Comment: I believe your error is that you substituted $r^2$ for $x^2\color{red}{-}y^2$.

Comment: but if I put a negative one next to it can the error be fixed

Comment: No.  Because $x^2-y^2 \ne (-1)(x^2+y^2)$

Comment: oh yes that is truee

Comment: @FernandoMartinez See my answer below. I've edited the mistake and added the limits of integral.

Answer (score 2):

Set $$x=r\cos\varphi,\:  y=r\sin\varphi$$

$$x^2+\frac{y^2}{16}=4\to r=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\cos^2\varphi+\frac{\sin^2\varphi}{16}}}$$

$$0\leq x\leq 2\to -\frac{\pi}{2}\leq \varphi\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Hence $$I=\iint f(r,\varphi)rdrd\varphi=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{2}{\sqrt{\cos^2\varphi+\frac{\sin^2\varphi}{16}}}} r^3\cos2\varphi drd\varphi$$

$$= 4\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos2\varphi}{\left(\cos^2\varphi+\frac{\sin^2\varphi}{16}\right)^2 }d\varphi=-120\pi$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The correct transformation is
$$
x=2\cos\theta
$$
and
$$
y=2r\sin\theta
$$
The limits of integral are $0\le\theta\le\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $-4\le r\le 4$. The Jacobian is $4\sin^2\theta$.
Try it! It works!  If this hint doesn't help you, just comment below. I'll answer it for you. ヾ(-^〇^-)ﾉ

Comment: ok I will try it

Comment: I thought x=rcos(theta) or are there more ways to write in polar coordinates

Comment: I think I see if you have $\int r cos^2(\theta)-r sin^2(\theta))(r)$

Comment: you factor out an r and get  $ \int r(r)\cos(2\theta)$

Comment: @FernandoMartinez Sorry, I've edited my answer. Please check it out. The answer is $-120\pi$. I've checked it both integrals using Wolfram Alpha. Click these links: [1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\int_0^2+\int_{-4\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{4\sqrt{4-x^2}}%28x^2-y^2%29+dy+dx) and [2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=16\int_0^{\pi%2F2}+\int_{-4}^{4}%28\cos^2+\theta+\sin^2+\theta-r^2+\sin^4+\theta%29++dr+d\theta).